# How can combine the map values with terraform?

Tags: terraform

I've tried this:

```
variable "records" {
  type = "map"
  default = {
    "mediapop.co." = ["www.mediapop.co"],
    "mediapopinc.com." = ["mediapopinc.com", "www.mediapopinc.com"] ,
    "mediapop.sg." = ["mediapop.sg", "www.mediapop.sg"],
  }
}

output "records" {
  value = "${flatten(values(var.records))}"
}
```

but `values()` only allows for flat maps. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [transpose](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#transpose-map-):

```
output "transpose" {
  value = "${transpose(var.records))"
}

output "values" {
  value = "${keys(transpose(var.records)))"
}
```

outputs

```
transpose = {
  mediapop.sg = [mediapop.sg.]
  mediapopinc.com = [mediapopinc.com.]
  www.mediapop.co = [mediapop.co.]
  www.mediapop.sg = [mediapop.sg.]
  www.mediapopinc.com = [mediapopinc.com.]
}

values = [
    mediapop.sg,
    mediapopinc.com,
    www.mediapop.co,
    www.mediapop.sg,
    www.mediapopinc.com
]
```